# how request local gRPC server?

Tags: grpc, grpc-java, grpc-web

I have a gRPC server, and I want to call this server by local channel like:

other message -> adapter -> local grpc client -> local grpc server

so how to create a local grpc client?, use local channel to build stub?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options:

1. also start your services with the InProcessServerBuilder, and use the InProcessChannelBuilder to communicate with it, or
2. just contact the server over "localhost"

Answer (score 1):

if you want a cli type of call to your local grpc server, you could checkout https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl